# Windows 7 compressing doesn't reduce space

Tags: windows-7, compression

I used the compression method by windows 7 from the properties of a file but it doesn't seem to work. The folder that was around 42,6 Gb is now 42,5 Gb which means it only saved me 100 MB?
Is there any other way to compress the files that i don't use (but i still want to keep)?

Comment: What kinds of files do you want to compress? With high-entropy files, you cannot achieve decent compression ratios.

Comment: Very likely most of that data is already compressed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what kind of algorithm Windows uses to compress filesystems, but it just could be that your data can't be easily compressed (mp3s, compressed video etc.)

You can try to pack the data into a .7z archive with 7-zip. It uses a quite efficient compression algorithm.

Comment: Is zip same as winrar?

Comment: 7zip is an open source software. You can find some information about in on wikipedia: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip
More information and downloads can be found at the official site at http://www.7-zip.org/